# 'Conversion from string "dd-MM-YYYY" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date, visual-studio-2019, datetimepicker

I have an insert query using SQL database. Insert query works well but when I use a DateTimePicker then it shows the error message above.
Can you tell me how to use a DateTimePicker in an insert query?

```
    Public Function SearchData(ByVal qr As String) As DataSet
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(qr, con)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        Return ds
    End Function

    Private Sub SaveEmp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveEmp.Click

        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
        Dim img() As Byte
        img = ms.ToArray()

        Dim insertquery As String = "Insert into AddNew(Userid,EmpSalary,EmpName,FatherName,EmailAddress,BankAccount,HomeAddress,PersonalMobile,DateofBirth,EmpImage) values(" & EmpID.Text _
 & "," & EmpSalary.Text & ",'" & EmpName.Text & "','" & FatherName.Text & "','" & EmailAddress.Text & "'," & BankAccount.Text & ",'" & HomeAddress.Text & "'," & PersonalMobile.Text & ",'" & DtpDOB.Value.Date.ToShortDateString("dd-MM-YYYY") & "',@img)"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(insertquery, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img
        ExecuteMyQuery(cmd, "Image Inserted")
    End Sub
```

Comment: You should create a parameter for every value that you want to insert into the database. As you do now for the Image field. In this way you avoid Sql Injection hacks and you don't need to translate a datetime value to a string format that your database can translate back to a datatime to correctly understand the value passed

Comment: Thanks Dear Steve i will do it and check then what happens.Thanks Again Dear for your time.Be happy.

Comment: Also it seems that your DateOfBirth field is an integer? How do you plan to store a datetime value in an integer field? On the other side, a phone number is never a number. If you have a phone number starting with 0 that zero will be trimmed away in a numeric field

Comment: Dear DateOfBirth field datatype is = Date in sql Now i have create parameters but one more error show me.please check this below.

Comment: Dim insertquery As String = "Insert into AddNew(Userid,EmpSalary,EmpName,FatherName,EmailAddress,BankAccount,HomeAddress,PersonalMobile,DateofBirth,EmpImage) values(@EmpID,@EmpSalary,@EmpName,@FatherName,@EmailAddress,@BankAccount,@HomeAddress,@PersonalMobile,@DtpDOB,@img)"

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EmpID.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpSalary", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EmpSalary.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmpName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FatherName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmailAddress.Text

Comment: Now Error is Must Declare Scalar variable @Userid

Comment: `@EmpID` not `@UserId`

Comment: `.AddWithValue `expects the value as the second parameter. It is not a good choice. Use the `.Add` method which does expect the type as the second parameter.

Comment: You left out several of the parameters in the statement from your .Add list. Is UserID and identity field? If so, do not include it in your sql statement or the parameters.

Comment: Please provide the datatype of each of the fields you are trying to insert. Also what is the primary key and is it an identity field?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question that was asked, this part  of the code doesn't make sense:

```
DtpDOB.Value.Date.ToShortDateString("dd-MM-YYYY")
```

You should have already read the relevant documentation and worked out the issue for yourself. That would have told you that the `ToShortDateString` method has no parameters. The whole point of that method is that it returns the specified date using the standard short date format for the current system.  This:

```
DtpDOB.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

is equivalent to this:

```
DtpDOB.Value.Date.ToString("d")
```

If you want a specific format, regardless of the system settings, then you need to call `ToString` and pass the appropriate custom format string:

```
DtpDOB.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MM-YYYY")
```

What is actually happening there is that the compiler is making a best guess at what you're trying to accomplish and it thinks that you are trying to index the `String` returned by `ToShortDateString`, i.e.

```
DtpDOB.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()("dd-MM-YYYY")
```

or like this:

```
Dim str As String = DtpDOB.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()
Dim ch As Char = str("dd-MM-YYYY")
```

That fails because indexing requires an `Integer` and that format string cannot be converted to an `Integer`, hence the error message.

As well as using parameters for ADO.NET, making format irrelevant, you should also turn `Option Strict On` in your project properties and the IDE options.

Comment: Thank u Dear you are really good man and genius man because you are very well teacher thank u so much in my heart.

Comment: Dear now i used this code " & DtpDOB.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") & " Now Code Run Successfully But Result show only in year like this -2020 now what i do.

Comment: One more issue in Personal Mobile no here is same problem here show only no but not show mobile code i mean full i enter full no in text box like this 0300-5752693 But Result show only in database table like this -5752693 why not show full no

Comment: You should probably update your question with any relevant new information.

Comment: @ob I wonder if you stored your dates in numbers and you hence ended up with  4-4-2020 (4 minus 4 minus 2020 = negative 2020). Use parameters like the man said! Read http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Thanks Dear i understand your sign.Thanks

Comment: @officialbaryar please remember to accept and upvote answers to your questions. You accept an answer by clicking the grey tick to turn it green. You upvote answers that are useful by clicking the up arrow. Any number of answers can be upvoted but only one can be accepted